# Deal with indexes of two lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

Let's say, I have two lists

```
id = [4,3,1,2],  
nm = ['d','c','a','b']
```

I want to bind indexes of both lists in such way, that if I sort the list 'id' :

```
id = sorted(id)
```

then, the list 'nm' must change according to indexes of list 'id' i.e.

```
id = [1,2,3,4],  
nm = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I have tried to bind lists using **zip**,

```
for i, n in zip(id,nm):
    name.append(n)
print(name)
```

but this will give me result of original 'nm' list.

Do I need to change something and play more with zip?

Comment: Why? What are you really trying to solve? seems like a better approach would be a dictionary